# Xtext Grammar-Mixin: Grammar Reference cant be resolved

Tags: reference, grammar, xtext, reusability

I want to reuse an exisitng Xtext grammar and I found out you can do it via mixins. So just to get started, I created a plain Xtext project to see if it works. Lets call it grammar B and the grammar to reuse A. I added a dependency to A in the Manifest file of B.

**Grammar B**

```
  grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDslB with 
  org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDslA

  generate myDslB "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDslB"

  Model:
  greetings+=Greeting*
  (invariants+=Invariant)*;

 Greeting:
  'Hello' name=ID '!';
```

**Grammar A**

```
 grammar edu.kit.ipd.sdq.xocl4inv.XOcl4Inv with org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase

 import "http://www.eclipse.org/xtext/xbase/Xbase" as xbase
 import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore
 import "http://www.eclipse.org/xtext/common/JavaVMTypes" as types

 generate myDslA "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDslA"

 *Rules follow here*
```

"Invariant" is a rule from grammar A that I want to reuse. So now the problem is, that Xtext cant find the reference to grammar A, although it is imported into the workspace and the dependency is added. I thought that maybe the URI is wrong but I entered it via suggestions(Ctrl+Space) and when clicking on it (Ctrl+Click on the URI), I get shown the original grammar file, so I dont think that something is wrong with it.

Is there maybe a step that I left out? Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: I would need to have a look at the code but I assume you did not add a project dependency from project b to project a

Comment: How did you add that dependency. Could you share reproducing dummy projects e.g. Via github